# Anonymize email address with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to hide an email address, but don't know how to have my expected answer. For example I want to see `hello@gmail.com` as `xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx`
and `barakobama@me.co` as `xxxxxxxxxx@xx.xx`

This is the code so far:

```
content = re.sub(r'.+(?=@.+?)', "xxxxx", email)
print(content)
```

However output is:
`xxxxx@gmail.com`

But I expect:

`xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx`

I am not forced to use regex! Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `re.sub(r'[^@.]', 'x', text)`?

Comment: Wow how easy! Thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In cases like this I wish `str.replace` would have accepted a function, so this would work `email.replace(lambda ch: ch not in {'@', '.'}, 'x')`. Sometimes using `re.sub` feels like an overkill

Comment: What about emails that escape the `@` such as: `"lol@example.com"@example.com`? That's a valid email address...

Comment: @DeepSpace Error! TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not function

Comment: @Braiano I wrote "I wish ... would work"... I was messing with an idea, not providing a solution

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes you're right, it could be a nice solution

Comment: @Giacomo Points for the trivia, but many live systems do not need to support all the esoteric RFC5321 variations which are not in common use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may replace all chars but `@` and `.` with an `x`:

```
text = re.sub(r'[^@.]', 'x', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rIWHUM/1)

The `[^@.]` pattern is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches any char but `.` and `@`.